# Flutter Navigator 2.0. Nested router with separate state

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm trying to create an app that has this structure:

[image: Expected widget tree]

I have several questions.

1. In what router delegate I should use `RouteInformationParser`? May be in both router delegates? I'd like to keep the authentication router and the nested router as separate as possible.
2. The same question applies to `setNewRoutePath`. In what router delegate I should implement it? Again in both?

In general may be this separate states idea is wrong. Should I abandon it and merge `AuthPathState` and `NestedPathState`? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually have separate `RouterDelegate` if you want to include additional `Navigator` widgets to allow "nested" navigation (for example preserving a `BottomNavigationBar` which is part of the widget currently shown by the root `Navigator` while navigating with the nested `Navigator`).

Therefore for the use case stated here, I would merge those to something like `AppPathState`.